# mysqldump without specifying location

Tags: mysql

I used `mysqldump` to dump the database without specifying the location.

```
mysqldump -u username -p database
```

And the dump was completed!

```
-- Dump completed on 2023-07-25 15:58:32
```

Is it possible that without making location file can the dump be stored?

If it's possible, is there a way that I can find that dump's location?

If it isn't possible, what happens to the dump that has been completed?

I tried to find the location of this dump but there were no logs, directory, filename etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no output file is specified when executing MySQL's dump command, by default, the output SQL data will be displayed on the terminal (command line window) instead of being saved to a file. This means that you will see the generated SQL statements output directly on the screen, but not saved to any files.This usage is usually used to view the results of the dump command or manually copy and paste these SQL statements elsewhere.

If you want to save directly in a file,you need to config the file.
`mysqldump [options] > dump.sql`.